# How to calculate $\nabla_{\mathbf{x}}(\mathbf{c}\mathbf{x}-A)\mathbf{x}^t$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus

How to calculate $\nabla_{\mathbf{x}}(\mathbf{c}\mathbf{x}-A)\mathbf{x}^t$ directly?

$\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{1\times n}$ , $\mathbf{c}\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times 1}$,  $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$.

My attempt:

Denote the expression $(\mathbb{c}\mathbf{x}-A)\mathbf{x}^t$ by $f$. Then, find $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}$

$f_i = ((\mathbf{c}\mathbf{x}-A)\mathbf{x}^t)_i = \sum_j c_ix_j^2-\sum_jA_{ij}x_j$

$\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j} = 2c_ix_j - A_{ij}$

So, $\nabla_\mathbf{x}(\mathbb{c}\mathbf{x}-A)\mathbf{x}^t = 2\mathbf{c}\mathbf{x}-A.$

---

Instead of calculating the $ij$-th component, how to compute the gradient directly?

Comment: Last row: $(c \mathbf{x} - A)\mathbf{x}^t = c || \mathbf{x} ||^2 - A\mathbf{x}^t$? But probably you are just missing the differential operator. I would go about the exact same way.

Comment: You just need to consider the formulas given there https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus. Here, $\Delta_x Ax=A$, and $\Delta_x x^TAx=(A+A^T)x$.

Comment: That "bulky" notation can be ambiguous in some cases, much better to use "abstract indexes" to make clear what is "contracted" with what, that is exactly what you did (your result is correct).

Answer (score 1):

The map $h : x \mapsto  (cx-A)x^T$ is defined on $\mathbb R^n$ and takes its values in $\mathbb R^m$. Hence you can't really speak of the [gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient) as $h$ is not a scalar-valued function.

However, you can speak of the [Fréchet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative) (or total) derivative of $h$ at a point $x$.

$f : x \mapsto cx-A$ is an affine map, therefore its Fréchet derivative is constant and equal at each $x \in \mathbb R^n$ to the linear map $u \mapsto cu$. $B : (C,x) \mapsto Cx^T$ is a bilinear map, whose Fréchet derivative at $(C,x)$ is the map $(U,v) \mapsto Ux^T +Cv^T$.

Based on the chain rule, you get

$$h^\prime(x)(u) = (cu)x^T + (cx-A)u^T$$ where $h^\prime(x)$ is the Fréchet derivative of $h$ at $x$.

Moreover because matrix product is associative and inner product commutative, you have
$$(cu)x^T= c(u x^T) = c(xu^T) = (cx)u^T$$ which allows to conclude to

$$h^\prime(x)(u) = (2cx-A)u^T.$$

In terms of [Matrix calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus), it means that
$$\frac{\partial h}{\partial x} = 2cx - A.$$

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on previous answers, you can use a full differential approach to compute the Jacobian of
$
\mathbf{u}=
[\mathbf{c}\mathbf{x}^T-\mathbf{A}]\mathbf{x}
$.

Note: I think it is better to represent vectors as column vectors (so I swapped the transpose)

From here
$$
d\mathbf{u}=
[\mathbf{c}\mathbf{x}^T-\mathbf{A}] d\mathbf{x}+
[\mathbf{c}(d\mathbf{x})^T]\mathbf{x}
$$
The second term writes
$\mathbf{c} \mathbf{x}^T d\mathbf{x} $

Finally the Jacobian is the matrix
$$
\frac{\partial \mathbf{u}}{\partial \mathbf{x}}
=
[\mathbf{c}\mathbf{x}^T-\mathbf{A}]+\mathbf{c} \mathbf{x}^T
=
2\mathbf{c} \mathbf{x}^T - \mathbf{A}
$$

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that many people understand a derivative as being defined by $\nabla_x f = \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}, \dots, \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n} \right)$ (and usually as a column vector).

For me, what made me understand derivatives better (and I can't promise this will be helpful for everyone) is to think a bit more abstractly. I also can't promise that you'll walk away from reading this with 100% understanding, but if you are interested in learning more, this is the subject of "differential geometry"/"differntial topology" so you can look into that if you're curious.

Given a function $f : N^n \to M^m$ between two manifolds (e.g. vector spaces), the derivative $(df)_x : TN \to TM$ is the "best linear approximation to $f$ at $x$." In concrete terms, for $f : \mathbf{R}^n \to \mathbf{R}^m$, the derivative is the $m \times n$ matrix $(df)_x$ such that

$$f(x + h) = f(x) + (df)_xh + o(h)$$

which is Taylor's theorem essentially but now taken as a definition. The reason for this is that the usual definition:

$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h} = f'(x)$$

doesn't make sense when $f, x, h$ are vectors. Instead we rearrange it as so:

$$ 0 = \lim_{h \to 0} \left( \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h} - f'(x) \right) \leadsto \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x + h) - f(x) - f'(x)h}{h} = 0$$

then replace the denominator by $|h|$ (the norm). You can see exactly that this is saying that

$$f(x + h) = f(x) + f'(x)h + o(h).$$

Given this definition, the form of the gradient I wrote at the very beginning is now a theorem (when $m = 1$). This definition has the nice property that it is now "obvious" that a linear function is its own derivative. That is, if $f(x) = Ax$ then $f'(x) = f = A$ (without the $x$ on the right). Note that

$$f(x + h) = f(x) + f(h)$$

so this has the form $f(x + h) = f(x) + (df)_xh + o(h)$ with $(df)_x = f$ and $o(h) = 0$.

Likewise, when you have a bilinear map $x^Tx$ you can compute $(x + h)^T(x + h)$ and write it as

$$\underbrace{(x + h)^T(x + h)}_{f(x + h)} = \underbrace{x^Tx}_{f(x)} + \underbrace{2x^T}_{(df)_x}h + \underbrace{h^Th}_{o(h)}. $$

---

More abstractly, one has the chain rule:

$$(d(f\circ g))_x = (df)_y \circ (dg)_x$$

and the Leibnitz rule:

$$(d(f \otimes g))_{x\otimes y} =  (df)_x \otimes g(y) + f(x) \otimes (dg)_y.$$

And we have $x^Tx = \operatorname{tr}(x^* \otimes x)$ which is a composition of the linear function $\operatorname{tr}$ and the function $x^* \otimes x = (I^* \otimes I)(x)$. Thus, using the chain rule and Leibnitz rule, we have

$$(dx^Tx)_x = (d\operatorname{tr})_{x^* \otimes x} \circ [(dx^*)_x \otimes x + x^* \otimes (dx)_x] = \operatorname{tr} \circ [I^* \otimes x + x^* \otimes I]$$

As a function of $h$, this is

$$\operatorname{tr} \left( [I^* \otimes x + x^* \otimes I] h \right) = \operatorname{tr}(h^* \otimes x + x^* \otimes h) = h^Tx + x^Th = 2x^Th.$$

That gives us the derivative $(dx^Tx)_x = 2x^T$.